# JAVA_Runtime_Error :- Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, collections, comparable

I am getting this error while I'm trying to sort the arraylist of nodes.I've tried most of the solutions, but none of them worked in my case.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(ComparableTimSort.java:866)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:483)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:406)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:213)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1312)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1506)
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
at j...
```

Code for this is

```
static class Node implements Comparable<Node>
{
    int key;
    int value;
    int double_value;

    public Node(int key , int value , int double_value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.double_value = double_value;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node node)
    {
        if(double_value < node.double_value)
            return 1;
        else if(double_value > node.double_value)
            return -1;

        return -1;
    }
}
```

It works for small inputs, but when the the number of inputs are large it gives this error. I've also read about the Transitivity rule in comparison method, but I can't figure out how it is applied in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You return -1 if two nodes have equal values, which means that a node can be simultaneously less than and greater than some other node, depending on in which order you compare. This indeed violates contract of `Comparable.compareTo` (and common sense is violated as well, for that matter). For simple case of comparing doubles, prefer `Double.compare` method instead.

Comment: Your `compareTo` never returns `0` to indicate they are the same, and you should also override `equals()` so two Nodes holding the same double_value `n1.equals(n2)` returns true.  When you override equals you should also override `hashcode()`

Comment: No underscores please! Follow the Java Naming Convention and replace `double_value` by `doubleValue`.

Comment: Identifiers should represent purpose and role, not (incorrectly) the implementation, and should be spelled according to the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are actually comparing `int` values (despite it being named *double*_value) you can have a very simple compareTo method

```
public int compareTo(Node node)
{
    return this.double_value - node.double_value;
}
```

You don't have to return -1, 0, or +1 — any negative or positive value will do.
The documentation for `compareTo()` says:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So

```
Node node1 = new Node(5, 5, 5);
Node node2 = new Node(7, 7, 7);
System.out.println( node1.compareTo(node2) );
```

will produce -2 because 5 is less than 7.

When you override compareTo you should also override `.equals(Node other)`, and when you override equals you should [also override `hashCode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java).

---

Update for better safety per Chris Parker's comment, this goes back to using -1, 0, 1 for the results:

```
public int compareTo(Node other)
{
    final long m = (long) this.double_value = (long) other.double_value;
    return m < 0 ? -1 :
           m > 0 ?  1 :
           0;
}
```

Comment: Be cautious using subtraction for your comparison.  Depending upon the numbers contained, you can exceed the value of a signed 32 bit integer, and overflow will cause an invalid return.

Comment: That is true @Chris ... you could end up with `Integer.MIN_VALUE - Integer.MAX_VALUE` which comes out incorrectly as `1`.  You can cast to widen, like `long m = (long)a  -  (long)b;` to make it safer.